# random image placement and clicking game using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image

i'm trying to create an easter egg hunt game that with place the image randomly throughout the page ,placement will change every time the user clicks it.

Comment: "*[I'm] trying to create...*" - great; how far did you get, and where did you get stuck? What problem did you need help with? What went wrong with your code?

Comment: i got the score part working but im not sure how to make the image appear at a random location when the user clicks it

Comment: This will get you started: http://uisacad5.uis.edu/~bconroy/Bingo_Scramble/index.html ask a question when you have some code.

Comment: okay um... this is a bingo game?? how will you help me??

Comment: @CoolioShire I'm not!  Take a look at the source for the bingo generator though, it has most of what you will need to do what you want (random image placement, etc...)  This is stackoverflow, not mechanical turk.